# Permutation of files

Tags: python, r, bash, perl, awk

I have 50 files in a directory, and I want to perform a permutation and get all possible combinations in groups of 25. If you want to see a small example, using groups od 3, it would be like this:

```
file1 file2 file3
file1 file2 file4
file1 file2 file5
...
file50 file48 file49
```

For that, I am using an R approach:

```
library(gtools)
args <- commandArgs(TRUE)

files <- list.files(args[1])
permutations(length(files), round(length(files)/2), files, repeats=FALSE)
```

This approach is extremely slow. Do you know some faster alternatives using `awk`, `bash`, `python`, `perl`?

Comment: This question really needs some example input/output to give a meaningful answer.

Comment: I think that's because the answer is `50! / (25! * 25!)` which is a very, very large number

Comment: Tried like this in R `do.call(paste,expand.grid(rep(list(1:5),3)))` But this try to create a vector of 58GB with 1:50 and 25 repeats, which is far away from my computer memory, so I assume it's a bad idea :)

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish? Every permutation of 25 out of 50 elements will always be huge. 50 factorial is 3 x 10 ^ 64, which is rather a lot of zeros. Even if you are 'just' taking 25 of them, that's still more than 15,511,210,043,330,985,984,000,000 which is 25!

Comment: If I computed it properly it's 1.264106e+14 possibilities, I.e: 126 410 606 437 752

Answer (score 1):

Using Python you could use the `combinations` function as follows:

```
from itertools import combinations
import os

for combo in combinations(os.listdir('.'), 25):
    print combo
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [perl faq](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq4.html#How-do-I-permute-N-elements-of-a-list%3F):

```
use Algorithm::Permute;
my @array = 'a'..'d';
my $p_iterator = Algorithm::Permute->new ( \@array );
while (my @perm = $p_iterator->next) {
   print "next permutation: (@perm)\n";
}
```

This generates every permutation of a list, although with 50 elements, that'll be quite a few.

I'm not sure if there's a handy way to select - and filter - sub lists. My initial thought would be to maintain a 'seen' list. I would start thinking in terms of maintaining a 'seen' list in a hash, and skipping duplicates, but you have to have generated the full permutation list to do that.

Alternatively there's [combine](http://search.cpan.org/~allenday/Math-Combinatorics-0.09/lib/Math/Combinatorics.pm#combine())

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Math::Combinatorics;

my @array      = 1 .. 9;
my $count = 0;
foreach my $comb ( combine (3, @array )) {
   print @$comb,"\n";
   print $count++,"\n";
}
```

3 way combinations is: 19,000 odd. 
4 is: 230300
5 is:

No idea what 25 is - I wasn't prepared to run it!

But note - it's a big operation, so will take a while regardless of what you do.